# how to keep cursor on same position in Jquery

Tags: jquery, refresh

i have created a Sharepoint webpart in that i have 3 tabs and a Repeater placed inside an update panel. While clicking on the button my page is refreshing and control is going to top. Please provide me some help. Thanks in advance.
By
Nani

Comment: Some help doing what?  What exactly is the question and where is the code?

Answer (score -1):

Likely because of `#` used in `<a href='#'>hello</a>` which makes the browser scroll to top. Find a way to remove it, or replace it with `<a href='javascript:;'>hello?</a>`.

Comment: Inline JavaScript is bad enough and yet you recommend doing something even worse; `href='javascript:;'`.  He's using jQuery, so a simple `preventDefault()` within his click handler would work... IF that's even the problem he's talking about.